# PHP - file_get_contents get JSON with regex, but can't JSON decode (got JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX)

Tags: javascript, php, json, regex

I try to parse this page : http://fr.hearthhead.com/cards to get the hearthstoneCards JS variable.
So i do something like this :

```
$url = 'http://fr.hearthhead.com/cards';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('#var hearthstoneCards = (.*)}]\;#Us', $content, $out);
$out = $out[1].'}]';
$tab_id_card = json_decode($out,true);
```

I try every tricks i could find (trim, stripslashes, preg for BOM and other things, put flags on json_decode and many other things), but i didn't get this working.

If i file_put_contents the $out var and compare to the real source it's the same thing (same length). If i put the string on a JS console, i get the data. But PHP don't want to parse this var :(

Some one got an idea ? :)

Comment: I don't get a `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` here, `json_decode()` merely returns `NULL`. Are you sure you get this error?

Comment: By checking json_last_error() cause it return NULL, thank you for testing it ! :)

Comment: Not all of the property names are in double-quotes, e.g. `{ ...., popularity:2 }`. While valid in javascript, it's not in JSON, therefore the parse-error. `$out = str_replace('popularity:', '"popularity":', $out);` would be an unstable quick-fix for now....

Comment: Ho didn't see that @VolkerK so now my only way is to build a regex to transform that, maybe it's even not possible, that's sad :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assume that code is JSON, when it's really full-fledged JavaScript. Within that code, many unquoted repetitions of the property name `popularity` occur, which is fine JavaScript but invalid JSON.

I tried to build a regex to fix any unquoted property names. Problem is, it's infeasible. In my case, any colons inside values broke my regex.

Short of writing a parser to fix such nonconformities or invoking a JS interpreter (which would require an external dependency such as V8Js), I think you'll be fine with fixing this specific scenario for now:

```
$url = 'http://fr.hearthhead.com/cards';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('#var hearthstoneCards = (.*)}]\;#Us', $content, $out);
$out = str_replace('popularity', '"popularity"', $out);
$out = $out[1].'}]';
$tab_id_card = json_decode($out,true);
```

If you worry about future introduction of new unquoted properties, you can check `$tab_id_card` for `NULL` and either log the error somewhere you routinely check or even go as far as somehow firing a notification for yourself. Although I'd do it, I'd say it's not a likely scenario, due to all the other properties being correctly quoted.